# Library speech not found... What should I do?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

```
10-20 18:40:02.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851): Uncaught handler: thread pool-1-       thread-1 exiting due to uncaught exception
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.RecognitionActivity.startRecognition(RecognitionActivity.jav  a:825)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.RecognitionActivity$RecognitionRunnable.run(RecognitionActivity.java:383)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library speech not found
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.endpointer.MicrophoneInputStream.<clinit>(MicrophoneInputStream.java:33)
10-20 18:40:02.102: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21851):     ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask user to install speech recognition software or [disable](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html) this function if such software not found.